# Star Rating Rich Snippets Not Showing on Google

Tags: google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I have tried several ways to try to get Rich Snippets Markup showing for my Reviews. I am currently just testing it on one page in order to find out what to do to get it to show on Google.

I have re-indexed my site and no luck.

Google says for the test that it is working correctly, but I cannot get it to show up.

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I am lost.

https://bitcoincasinolord.com/casino-reviews/bitstarz/

​

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Review",
  "url": "https://bitcoincasinolord.com/casino-reviews/bitstarz-casino-review/",
  "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Bitstarz Casino"
  },
  "reviewRating": {
    "@type": "Rating",
    "ratingValue": "8.9",
    "bestRating": "10",
    "worstRating": "0"
  },
  "author": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "BitcoinCasinoLord"
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not must to show the everything as rich results. if you page passes rich result test that's good but google decides what to show as rich result. it depends upon many factors.

[Reasons Why Your Rich Snippets Aren’t Showing](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/why-your-rich-snippets-are-not-appearing/203720/#close)

Comment: Thank you! 

The code itself, is that correct in theory? Did I do anything wrong in it?

Comment: your review structured Data is not wrong but your article's microdata has some errors that can also be the reason